# Centos 6 yum update failure

Tags: centos, command, putty, rpm

trying a simple yum update logged as root via Putty gives me:

```
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:1.12.4-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.7 for package: python-paramiko-1.124-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Conflict: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 conflicts filesystem < 3
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-15.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64 (@base)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Not found
Error: Package: python-paramiko-1.12.4-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
               python(abi) = 2.6

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

the expection is longer but stack can't let me put everything without write the same quantity of text...
Anyways...
I really can't understand why it does that conflict problem...
can anybody point at least me to the right direction?

edit: if i launch yum update --skip-broken

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 from epel
    libdb4-cxx-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 from epel
    libdb4-devel-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 from epel
    libdb4-utils-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 from epel
    python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    python-ecdsa-0.11-3.el7.noarch from epel
    python-paramiko-1.12.4-1.el7.noarch from epel
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the CentOS 7 EPEL repositories enabled on your CentOS 6 machine. This is not going to work correctly.

Replace those with the CentOS 6 EPEL repositories and then make sure you don't accidentally have any CentOS 7 packages installed (since those will continue to cause problems like this going forward).

You will want to downgrade any packages that `rpm -qa | grep \\.el7\\.` finds.

Comment: i removed epel 7...then re-installed 6, now if i do rpm -qa | grep \\.el7\\.
it gaves me vconfig-1.9-16.el7.x86_64
i have to remove this file? pls guide i'm a newbie on linux centos...

Comment: If that's the only `el7` package you have it might not be that bad but yes, you should replace that `el7` package with the appropriate `el6` package. `yum downgrade vconfig` *might* be enough to make that work... alternatively you could just remove it and `yum install vconfig` now that the repos are sorted out to install the correct version.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on a virtual server with CENTOS 6.4

```
yum remove epel-release
yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

It was true that I mistakenly used Epel repository for Centos 7 in Centos 6 machine. And I tried above solution but they did the trick half way. Here is what finally worked for me.

1. yum remove epel-release
2. rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
3. yum clean all
4. yum repolist
5. yum update -y